# Order of mixed menu 'action' and 'command' menu items in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, menu, eclipse-rcp

At the moment I have two menus in my RCP application:
File and Help.

The **File** menu is created via a `command`:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution allPopups="false" 
                    locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
     <menu
           id="fileMenu"
           label="File"
           mnemonic="F"
           tooltip="Main Menu">
        <command
              commandId="myPlugin.bundle.menuCommands.Exit"
              label="Exit"
              mnemonic="E"
              style="push"
              tooltip="Exits MyPlugin">
        </command>
     </menu>
  </menuContribution>
  </extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <command defaultHandler="myPlugin.bundle.commands.exit.ExitHandler"
        id="myPlugin.bundle.menuCommands.Exit"
        name="Exit">
  </command>
</extension>
```

The **Help** menu (with only the About menu item) is created via the respective `action` in `ApplicationActionBarAdvisor`:

```
protected void makeActions(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
    aboutAction = ActionFactory.ABOUT.create(window);
    register(aboutAction);
}

protected void fillMenuBar(IMenuManager menuBar) {
    MenuManager helpMenu = new MenuManager("&Help", "helpMenu");
    helpMenu.add(aboutAction);
    menuBar.add(helpMenu);
}
```

Now, the **Help** menu comes before the **File** menu in the menu bar. This is obviously not how it's supposed to be. How can I change the order of the menus?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, solved this by simply adding a `MenuManager` in the `ApplicationActionBarAdvisor` for the **File** menu:

```
MenuManager helpMenu = new MenuManager("&Help", "helpMenu");
MenuManager fileMenu = new MenuManager("&File", "fileMenu");
...
menuBar.add(fileMenu);
menuBar.add(helpMenu);
```

Can I hear you go "d'uh!"? Cos that's what I did ;).

## UPDATE:

Is this really how it should be done though? That'd mean that for every new menu I create in the Extension Wizard, I'll have to add a new line to `ApplicationActionBarAdvisor`...

Perhaps you could share your thoughts on this, or whether it's just an avoidable hack.

Thanks!